# Receive data from apache webserver

Tags: java, apache, raspberry-pi3

I have installed apache web server on a Raspberry Pi. I made also an android application that connects to the server and post some requests successfully. The app "speaks" with an index.php file placed in the web server.
I installed a motion sensor on the Raspberry and I want the server to send data to the application if the motion sensor is triggered or not. Is there any way to do this or request the web server from the android app if the variable (e.x. motionstate) is "active"? If I need to provide more informations or parts of the code feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to have a a code snippet running in your server which periodically(Google for Event Handlers in PHP or Polling/Looping) checks if the value of the variable (ex motionstate) has turned to active and then inform the app using an API call(or the other way around ie Android App fires a call periodically to server running in device to get data). 
Refer to this for some idea: http://www.robertprice.co.uk/robblog/using-motion-sensor-raspberry-pi-php/